# How to Schedule Recurring Builds in App Center

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-build

I have an Android app in [App Center](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/app-center?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-bramin) and I'd like to schedule nightly builds.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer

Today, App Center Build [doesn't yet allow us to schedule recurring builds](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/328).

Luckily, App Center has a [complete suite of APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/appcenter/api-docs?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-bramin) we can leverage to schedule an [Azure Timer Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-bramin) (essentially a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) in the cloud) to trigger a build every night.

For a complete solution, see the UITestSampleApp.Functions project in this repo: https://github.com/brminnick/UITestSampleApp

### Walkthrough

For a complete walkthrough, follow this post: https://www.codetraveler.io/2019/06/06/scheduling-app-center-builds/

This shows how to gather the required metadata and API Token from App Center, then how to build an Azure Timer Function that will trigger a build via the App Center APIs.

#### 1. Get App Center Metadata

First, get the App Center metadata we'll need to `Post` to the App Center API

[image: App Center Build Metadata]

#### 2. Generate App Center API Token

Then generate an App Center API Token

[image: Generate App Center API Token]

#### 3. Create an Azure Timer Function

This Azure Timer Function uses the cron schedule `0 0 9 * * *` to trigger every day at 0900 UTC.

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

const string owner = "[Your App Owner]"; //change to your app owner
const string appName = "[Your App Name]"; // change to your app name
const string branch = "[Your Repo's Branch]"; //change to your repo's branch

readonly static Lazy<HttpClient> clientHolder = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() =>
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-Token", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppCenterApiToken"));

    return client;
});

static HttpClient Client => clientHolder.Value;

[FunctionName("AppCenterScheduledBuildFunction")]
public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 9 * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{    
    var httpContent = new StringContent("{ \"debug\": true }", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var result = await Client.PostAsync($"https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/{owner}/{appName}/branches/{branch}/builds", httpContent);

    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

#### 4. Add App Center API Token to Azure Function

In the Azure Function Application Settings, add the App Center API Token, generated in step 2, using `AppCenterApiToken` for its name.

[image: Azure Function Application Settings]

[image: Azure Function API Token]

Comment: This worked great!  I might point out though that I did have a few moments of frustration when I realized that the default time in Azure Functions is UTC!  If you want to have your functions run in your time zone, for instance, Eastern Standard Time, you must add the following:`WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` = `Eastern Standard Time`